# Convert a YYYYMM number to a date

Tags: sql

I have a column full of numbers that list year and month in YYYYMM format (i.e. 201607 for July 2016). What I'd like to know is if I can convert this into proper date format within SQL. I've seen a lot of answers regarding converting YYYYYMMDD form to a date, but not much with only the 6 characters I've got.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Anything in that format isn't a date, a date requires a day component.

Comment: Well, it's not a date, it's a month. What kind of date do you want? The first of the month? Middle? Always the 14th? The last of the month? When you decide that, it's trivial to get the other answer to work for you.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that every one would be the first of the month (i.e. `201807` would be `2018-07-01`):

```
CONVERT(date, YourColumn + '01')
```

If you require a different day in that month, you'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: Would be better as `CONCAT(YourColumn, '01')` instead of `YourColumn + '01'`. With the latter, data type precedence will convert `01` to an integer, rather than `201807` to a string, so you end up with a number which is 201808 - not only is this not the desired result, you cannot implicitly convert an integer to a date.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sensible to use 112 style here too?

Comment: @DavidG Doesnt that only works if your hardcode a day? And then you would get a fulldate. ex select convert(date,convert(varchar(8),201709)+'01',112) as date

Comment: @DavidG `yyyyMMdd` is a deterministic date format in SQL Server, no need for a style code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this if you want:

```
select *, FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1900, right(YearMonthKey,2), 1), 'MMMM', 'en-US') +' '+ Left(YearMonthKey,4) as MonthYearName
from (
    select 201709 as YearMonthKey
) x
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: the `FORMAT` method works on sql server and does not work, e.g. on mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Think To Do

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT('2022-01-24',7),'-','')
```

Result : 202201

Just Replace your Column and use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this
i have these value in sql.

FieldValue

1. 2023
2. 2023
3. 2023
4. 2023-04-01
5. 2023-05

`SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(FieldValue) <> 0 THEN CONVERT(DATE, FieldValue) ELSE CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(FieldValue,'-01'),23) END FROM #FieldValueTableenter code here`

Answer (score -1):

For Oracle:

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('**201607**', 'YYYYMM'), 'Month YYYY')

result: **July 2016**

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('**201607**', 'YYYYMM'), 'DD Month YYYY')

result: **01 July 2016**

it will use 01 as default day, so you can format your desire formatting