# How to convert nvarchar having yyyymm values to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, converters

I have a table which has a column 'performance month'. The data type of this column is nvarchar(255) and the values are starting from '202001' to '202012'. How can I select last 5 month data from this table?

Comment: Ideally, you should be fixing your design, don't use a `varchar` to store dates. Use a date and time data type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL- How to convert a YYYYMM number to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187669/sql-how-to-convert-a-yyyymm-number-to-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
select convert(date, performance_month + '01')
```

The standard string representation for dates is YYYYMMDD.

For data from the last five months, you can simply use:

```
performance_month >= format(dateadd(month, -5, getdate()), 'yyyyMM')
```

That is, don't convert the string to a date.  Convert the date to a string -- this helps the optimizer because it can "see" `performance_month` without the cloud of function calls.

Comment: Thanks, it worked from me.. How may I select data from last 5 months after converting this?